# How to launch XCUITests on more than one simulator from command line

Tags: ios, xcode

Does any one know how to launch XCUItest bundles from command line on more than one simulator?

I do not wish to use a third party frame work. I just want to know how to do it from command line.
Currently, I only know how to launch them on one simulator.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
xcodebuild test -workspace your_app.xcworkspace -scheme your_app_scheme -destination 'platform=iphonesimulator,name=iPad Air'
```

Also I recommend to read this article for using Ruby Rake library with Command line  http://cuckooforcocoadev.com/blog/2014/05/02/using-rake-for-command-line-builds/

If you use rake you will be able customize log of UI tests results.
According to this article:

```
xcodebuild -workspace your_app.xcworkspace -scheme '#{target_name}' -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release #{build_action} | xcpretty -tc ; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```